# Symfony 3: Fatal error: Class 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle' not found in AppKernel.php on line 21

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I am using "**HWIOAuthBundle**" along with "*FOSUserBundle*", which works pretty well on localhost (Windows). But when I upload it to live server, I get the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle' not found
>   in **/home/site/symfony3/app/AppKernel.php** on line 21

AppKernel.php has such entry:

```
$bundles = [
            ...,
            ...,
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new WhiteOctober\PagerfantaBundle\WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle(),
            new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
        ];
```

What could be the problem? I'm using Symfony 3.1.1 on Windows (localhost).
PS: I have no access to the terminal as it is a shared hosting, thus clear:cache is not possible. Alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

And you've followed these steps explicitly for Symfony3:

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md

So your composer.json has "hwi/oauth-bundle" in it - check that too.
And the Routing is setup?

Comment: Yes, I followed this very documentation and the value inside my composer.json's require is: `"hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.5.*-dev"`
Routers and all other settings are working normally on my localhost, where it is fully functional. This error is shown only on live site.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what exactly was the problem. Luckily it was a new project, so I did not have to worry about loosing any data. Here is what I did that fixed this hurdle for me.

*#1: Clean-up:*

- Deleted my `/vendor` folder [with ftp]
- Deleted the `/prod` folder inside cache/ [with ftp]
- Dropped all the tables (with phpMyAdmin)

*#2: Restoration:*

- Copied the local `/vendor` folder to the corresponding root folder online (with ftp)
- Exported my local database and imported it into online database (with phpMyAdmin)

When I re-loaded the website, the `Fatal error: Class 'HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle' not found in /home/site/symfony3/app/AppKernel.php on line 21` error was gone and worked normally. Hope this helps someone who is having the similar problem.